# Change DPI of Logitech Mouse

Tags: logitech

Okay so as the title says I want to be able to change my DPI in my Logitech G400 mouse to be exact. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Install `solaar` and see if their DPI settings apply to the G400.

See <strike>http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/</strike> for more information about `solaar`.

Add <strike>`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/solaar/ubuntu yakkety main`</strike> repository if you don't find `solaar` in the Ubuntu repositories.

- note: if you're using a Ubuntu newer than yakkety, you may have to manually change the Ubuntu version in `Software & Updates`, <strike>as yakkety was the latest repository for solaar</strike>.

To add the PPA, in `terminal`...

<strike>sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/solaar</strike>

To install, in `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solaar
```

Then pair the G400, and once paired, open the G400 settings and check/adjust the DPI.

**Update #1:**

Updated info...

[https://launchpad.net/~solaar-unifying/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Esolaar-unifying/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/solaar-unifying/stable/ubuntu groovy main

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:solaar-unifying/stable

Comment: Solaar doesn't seem to apply for the Logitech G400 device unfortunately. It says No Logitech receiver found. I have however found another way to change the DPI and the samping rate for the Logitech G400. 

If anyone is interested in it they can read more about it here [https://github.com/rprichard/logitech-g400-config](https://github.com/rprichard/logitech-g400-config)

Comment: @blazefantasyy it didn't find the Logitech receiver either because it's not a unifying receiver, or it needs the firmware update, or you need to plug it directly into a computer USB port, or you just need to unplug/reinsert it.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not a unifying receiver then as I have it plugged directly into a computer USB pot and have attempted to unplug and then plug it in again. Also I don't think theres any way to firmware update it if I'm on linux.

Comment: @blazefantasyy You paired the G400 with the Logitech Dongle in Windows, yes? If so, that's where to do the firmware update.

Comment: If you're asking if I have Logitech Gaming Software on Windows then yes, I do.

Comment: @blazefantasyy no, ultimately I was saying that you do the firmware update from Windows. Just like right now you have to pair the mouse with the Logitech receiver in Windows. Solaar is a Linux version of the Logitech software functionality. See https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D531000055gw8YCAQ/logitech-response-to-unifying-receiver-research-findings

Answer (score 0):

You may try this tool (designed for wireless mouse Logitech Performance MX) https://code.google.com/archive/p/mxdpi/downloads

More on that: https://derhofbauer.at/logitech-performance-mx/